# How to remove vertical yellow line?

Tags: phpstorm

I am Using PhpStorm EAP 2020.3 together with this theme: https://github.com/jesusOmar/one-dark-phpstorm

Everything looks good, except that there is a yellow vertical line indicating the tabs:

[image: https://github.com/jesusOmar/one-dark-phpstorm]

How can I disable that? I was looking in `Editor > Color Scheme > PHP` but the editor does not show any yellow lines in the preview:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Indent guide".

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General`
2. Locate `Editor | Guides | Indent guide` style
3. Change/remove background color for it.

[image]